# MS Visio 2010 hangs when editing UML diagrams

Tags: visio

On all four of my Windows 7 x64 Pro computers with Visio Pro 2010 installed, I have had the following problem for the past several months: When I edit a Visio document that uses the UML stencil, as soon as I try to edit any object information, for example, define a table column, Visio locks up. By ‘lock up’, the program ceases to respond, Task Manager shows that the process is consuming 13% of the CPU, and the process has to be terminated via Task Manager.

In an attempt to resolve this problem, I had tried repairing the installation and uninstalling/reinstalling the program, but this has not resolved the problem.

I recently attached Visual Studio to the process to try to better understand the issue. As expected, there were numerous messages of the type ‘Cannot find or open the PDB file.’ The messages which, I sense, may be relevant were as follows:

```
First-chance exception at 0x7713C54F (KernelBase.dll) in VISIO.EXE: 0x80040155: Interface not registered.
```

In an attempt to address this issues, I tried:

```
C:\>regsvr32 c:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
```

This resulted in a popup window with the following message:

```
The module “C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll” was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.
Make sure that “C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll” is a valid DLL or OCX file then try again.
```

The version of kernelBase.cll that is currently installed is 6.1.7601.24214, dated 1 Aug 2018 with a size of 419,840 bytes. 
I used MultiFind Pro to search C:\Windows for any files named KernelBase and found quite a few older version in C:\Windows\winsxs. There were also numerous folder of the type C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-kernelbase_[identifier]. As well as other, similar folders. (What I am finding very strange is that MultiFind Pro is reporting a different file size and date than Windows Explorer or the Windows command prompt DIR command for all versions of this file.)

The last time a Visio UML file was successfully edited was Dec 2017 and based on the modified dates of the files found, the last version of KernelBase that was known to work was version 6.1.7601.23418, dated 18 Jun 2016.

I am fairly certain that my computer does not have a virus. I also know that reinstalling Windows will not resolve the issue as I have the same issue across all of my computers.

If I were to try copying Kernelbase.ddl V6.1.7601.23418 from the winsxs ‘backup’ folder, would it simply get over-written by the newer versions?

More importantly, can anyone suggest a specific course of action to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes, try calling Microsoft support - they are the guys to fix such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Nikolay - I assume you are the MS Engineer who helped me with this issue - thanks.

Without boring everyone with the details: The problem occurs when my password manager, Sticky Password, is also running. Shut it down, and Visio works just fine. I have alerted the company and have asked them to fix the problem.